# send sms to mobile numbers through vb.net windows application using GSM modem

Tags: vb.net, sms, gsm

I have developed a windows application in vb.net and now my client wants to add sms feature in that application. i have never used sms feature before so don't have any idea how to get it done. Can anyone tell me how to use GSM modem in order to send sms to recipients through vb.net application?
So far i have designed a GUI with NumberTextBox and SMSBodyTextBox and SendSMSButton. The sms should be sent to number entered in the NumberTextBox including the SMSBody when the user clicks SendSMSButton.
PS: SMS will be sent only by GSM Modem using Local network Sim Card.
Any support regarding this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: check this - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com

Comment: check out this 1.http://www.activexperts.com/sms-component/howto/gsm-send/vbnet/ 2.https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sending-SMS-Using-PC-COM-3d79e1d7